# Basic C# calculator (+,-,*,/) - V2

Tags: c#, beginner, classes, math-expression-eval, calculator

Original question:

[Basic C# calculator (+,-,*,/)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67054/basic-c-calculator)

My 'teacher' requested this problem be solved by parsing the input into a tree based on the order of operations. The class Calc variables are specific to his instruction (except precedence) as well as the `getValue()` method. Everything else is subject to review.

I'm hoping to receive detailed input on how to make my code meet best practices as closely as possible in the perspective of a much larger program to be more familiar with programs to come.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace calcTree
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Various prompt and response strings
            const string WELCOME = "Welcome to the Calculator!";
            const string INSTRUCTIONS = "\nPlease enter an equation (do not use '=' or parenthesis):" +
                                        "\nEnter \"exit\" or \"bye\" to quit.\n";
            const string INVALID_INPUT = "\nYour input was invalid.";
            const string EXIT = "\nGoodbye!";
            string[] EXIT_KEY = { "exit", "bye" };

            Console.WriteLine(WELCOME);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(INSTRUCTIONS);
                string equation = Console.ReadLine();  // Read equation
                equation = equation.Replace(" ", String.Empty);   // Remove spaces

                // Check for program exit keywords
                if (equation.EndsWith(EXIT_KEY[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    equation.EndsWith(EXIT_KEY[1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(EXIT);
                    break;
                }
                // Validate the equation
                else if (!Calc.ValidateEquation(equation))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(INVALID_INPUT);
                }
                // Solve the equation
                else
                {
                    string[] answers = Calc.Solve(equation);
                    for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length; i++) // Print the answer
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(answers[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Read(); // Waits for 'enter' to end.
        }
    }
}
```

**CalcTree.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace calcTree
{
    class Calc
    {
        char oper;
        decimal num;
        int precedence; // Assists with print order, not the actual calculation.

        Calc left;
        Calc right;

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests for NULL, that all chars are numbers or operators and that the last
        /// char is a number.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="equation">User input equation</param>
        /// <returns>True if valid</returns>
        public static bool ValidateEquation(string equation)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(equation) ||     // test for null
                !Char.IsNumber(equation[equation.Length-1]))  // last char must be a number
            {
                return false;
            }

            // All chars must be a number or operator
            for (int i = 0; i < equation.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!Char.IsNumber(equation[i]))
                {
                    if (equation[i] != '*' &&
                        equation[i] != '/' &&
                        equation[i] != '+' &&
                        equation[i] != '-' &&
                        equation[i] != '.')
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Solves the equation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="equation">String of valid numbers and operators</param>
        /// <returns>String[] of the solution in the order of operations</returns>
        public static string[] Solve(string equation)
        {
            string[] parsedInput = ParseEquation(equation);
            Calc[] logicTree = AllocateLogicTree(parsedInput);
            logicTree = ApplyLeftLogic(logicTree);
            logicTree = ApplyRightLogic(logicTree);
            string[] answer = SolveLogicTree(logicTree);
            return answer;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parse input string into an array so that assignments to the logic tree are clear.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="equation">User input equation</param>
        /// <returns>string[] containing separated numbers and operators</returns>
        static string[] ParseEquation(string equation)
        {
            int size = 0;   // "word" count for array size
            for (int i = 0; i < equation.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i + 1 < equation.Length)
                {
                    if (equation[i + 1] == '*' || equation[i + 1] == '/' || equation[i + 1] == '+' || equation[i + 1] == '-')
                        size++;
                }
            }
            size = size * 2 + 1;    // operators * 2 + 1 == array positions required

            string[] parsedInput = new string[size]; // Allocates array size

            // Parse string into array by numbers and operators
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            size = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < equation.Length; j++)
            {
                if (equation[j] != '*' && equation[j] != '/' && equation[j] != '+' && equation[j] != '-')
                {
                    sb.Append(equation[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    parsedInput[size] = sb.ToString(); // Add number to array
                    sb.Clear();
                    size++;
                    parsedInput[size] = equation[j].ToString();   // Add operator to array
                    size++;
                }
            }
            parsedInput[size] = sb.ToString(); // Add last number to array

            return parsedInput;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Assigns string[] to eqaul sized Calc[], string[] value is either Calc.oper or Calc.num.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parsedEquation">String[] containing separated numbers and operators</param>
        /// <returns>Calc[] with either .num or .oper assigned to each index</returns>
        static Calc[] AllocateLogicTree(string[] parsedEquation)
        {
            Calc[] logicTree = new Calc[parsedEquation.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < parsedEquation.Length; i++)
                logicTree[i] = new Calc();

            for (int j = 0; j < parsedEquation.Length; j++)
            {
                if (parsedEquation[j] == "*" || parsedEquation[j] == "/" || parsedEquation[j] == "+" || parsedEquation[j] == "-")
                {
                    logicTree[j].oper = Char.Parse(parsedEquation[j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    logicTree[j].num = Decimal.Parse(parsedEquation[j]);
                }
            }
            return logicTree;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies the order of operations logic for the .left branches.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logicTree">Each index contains .num or .oper</param>
        /// <returns>logicTree with .left assigned and precedence.</returns>
        static Calc[] ApplyLeftLogic(Calc[] logicTree)
        {
            // .left requirements & assign initial values before .right can be determined for + and -.
            for (int i = 0; i < logicTree.Length; i++)
            {
                if (logicTree[i].oper == '*' || logicTree[i].oper == '/')
                {
                    // Previous oper must be + or - // else .left = previous * or / oper
                    if (i - 2 >= 0) // bounds checking
                    {
                        if (logicTree[i - 2].oper == '+' || logicTree[i - 2].oper == '-')
                            logicTree[i].left = logicTree[i - 1];
                        else // previous operator must be * or /
                            logicTree[i].left = logicTree[i - 2];
                    }
                    else logicTree[i].left = logicTree[i - 1];
                    logicTree[i].right = logicTree[i + 1]; // always
                    logicTree[i].precedence = 1; // Calculate this 1st
                }
                else if (logicTree[i].oper == '+' || logicTree[i].oper == '-')
                {
                    // Previous oper must not exist or link to previous + or -
                    if (i - 2 >= 0) // bounds checking
                    {
                        for (int j = i - 2; j >= 0; j--)
                        {
                            if (logicTree[j].oper == '+' || logicTree[j].oper == '-')
                            {
                                logicTree[i].left = logicTree[j];
                                break;
                            }
                            j--;
                        }
                        if (logicTree[i].left == null) // logicTree[l - 2] must be the last * or / & the correct assignment
                            logicTree[i].left = logicTree[i - 2];
                    }
                    else logicTree[i].left = logicTree[i - 1];
                    // wait to assign .right
                    logicTree[i].precedence = 2; // Calculate this 2nd
                }
            }
            return logicTree;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies the order of operations logic for the .right branches.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logicTree">Each index contains .num or .oper</param>
        /// <returns>logicTree with .right assigned.</returns>
        static Calc[] ApplyRightLogic(Calc[] logicTree)
        {
            // .right requirements for + and -
            for (int i = 1; i < logicTree.Length; i++)
            {
                if (logicTree[i].oper == '+' || logicTree[i].oper == '-')
                {
                    // if tree.oper + 2 == * or /, check next tree.oper and assign .right to the last consecutive * or /
                    if (i + 2 < logicTree.Length) // bounds checking
                    {
                        if (logicTree[i + 2].oper == '*' || logicTree[i + 2].oper == '/')
                        {
                            int j; // represents last * or /
                            for (j = i + 2; j < logicTree.Length; j++) // assign .right to last consecutive * or /
                            {
                                if (logicTree[j].oper != '*' && logicTree[j].oper != '/')
                                {
                                    logicTree[i].right = logicTree[j - 2];
                                    break;
                                }
                                j++;
                            }
                            if (logicTree[i].right == null) // if not assigned from the for loop, last * or / must be (o - 2)
                                logicTree[i].right = logicTree[j - 2];
                        }
                        else logicTree[i].right = logicTree[i + 1];
                    }
                    else logicTree[i].right = logicTree[i + 1];
                }
                i++;
            }
            return logicTree;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns decimal value or if performed on an operator returns the solution of
        /// left (operator) right.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>num value or solution</returns>
        decimal GetValue()
        {
            if (oper == 0) // tests for operator
                return num;
            else
                switch (oper)
                { // recursively calculates down the "tree", logical order determined in applyLogic()
                    case '+':
                        return left.GetValue() + right.GetValue();
                    case '-':
                        return left.GetValue() - right.GetValue();
                    case '*':
                        return left.GetValue() * right.GetValue();
                    case '/':
                        return left.GetValue() / right.GetValue();
                    default: return 0; // never returns 0
                }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Solves logicTree by the order of operations.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logicTree">.left, .right, and precedence are assigned</param>
        /// <returns>string[] of answers in the order of operations</returns>
        static string[] SolveLogicTree(Calc[] logicTree)
        {
            int answersIndex = 1; // 1 extra index for final answer
            for (int i = 0; i < logicTree.Length; i ++)
            {
                if (logicTree[i].oper != '\0')
                    answersIndex++;
            }
            string[] answers = new string[answersIndex];
            answersIndex = 0;

            int precedence = 1; // starts with * and /
            while (precedence != 3)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < logicTree.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (logicTree[j].oper != 0 && logicTree[j].precedence == precedence)
                        answers[answersIndex] = "\n" + logicTree[j].left.GetValue() + " " + logicTree[j].oper + " " + logicTree[j].right.GetValue() + " = " + logicTree[j].GetValue();
                }
                precedence++;
            }
            answers[answers.Length - 1] = "\nThe answer is: " + logicTree[logicTree.Length - 2].GetValue();
            return answers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The original code should still remain unchanged from answers, even for follow-up questions.

Answer (score 7):

Just at a real quick glance, inside the loop in `ValidateEquation`, you access `equation[i]` many times.

> ```
>      for (int i = 0; i < equation.Length; i++)
>         {
>             if (!Char.IsNumber(equation[i]))
>             {
>                 if (equation[i] != '*' &&
>                     equation[i] != '/' &&
>                     equation[i] != '+' &&
>                     equation[i] != '-' &&
>                     equation[i] != '.')
>                 {
>                     return false;
> ```

I would consider using a local `character` variable so that you don't have to continually get the value from the string, but simply return it once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < equation.Length; i++)
{
    char character = equation[i]; 

    if (!Char.IsNumber(character))
    {
        if (character != '*' &&
            character != '/' &&
            character != '+' &&
            character != '-' &&
            character != '.')
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Also, I think most C# devs would expect `ValidateEquation` to be named `IsValidEquation` to indicate that it returns a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your suggestions in my code and above. I like making equation[i] more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

**ParseEquation() method**

You are iterating 2 times over the characters of `equation`. The first time to get the size of the array you wish to return, the second to parse the `equation`.

A better approach would be to use a `ILIst<String>`.

You are using a `for` loop where a `foreach` loop would be better, as you would have less to type.

Because the `AllocateLogicTree` is the only method using the output, we can let the `ParseEquation` method return an [`IEnumerable<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which we can then use as input parameter for the `AllocateLogicTree` method.

After applying these, your method could be refactored to

```
static IEnumerable<String> ParseEquation(string equation)
{
    IList<String> parsedInput = new List<String>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Char c in equation)
    {
        if (c != '*' && c != '/' && c != '+' && c != '-')
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            parsedInput.Add(sb.ToString());
            parsedInput.Add(c.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
        }
    }
    parsedInput.Add(sb.ToString());

    return parsedInput;
}
```

**AllocateLogicTree() method**

Again you are iterating 2 times over the array. This isn't necessary.

You are using `Char.Parse` for strings where you know that it contains an operator. You can access the char by using the index.

You can use a `foreach` also.

As you aren't just allocationg an logic tree, but building one by filling with values a better name would be `CreateLogicTree`.

After applying these, your method could be refactored to

```
static Calc[] CreateLogicTree(IEnumerable<String> parsedEquation)
{
    IList<Calc> logicTree = new List<Calc>();

    foreach (String currentEquationItem in parsedEquation)
    {
        if (currentEquationItem == "*" || currentEquationItem == "/"
            || currentEquationItem == "+" || currentEquationItem == "-")
        {
            logicTree.Add(new Calc() { oper = currentEquationItem[0] });
        }
        else
        {
            logicTree.Add(new Calc() { num = Decimal.Parse(currentEquationItem) });
        }
    }
    return logicTree.ToArray();
}
```

This can be then called in the `Solve()` method like

```
    public static string[] Solve(string equation)
    {
        IEnumerable<String> parsedInput = ParseEquation(equation);
        Calc[] logicTree = CreateLogicTree(parsedInput);
        logicTree = ApplyLeftLogic(logicTree);
        logicTree = ApplyRightLogic(logicTree);
        string[] answer = SolveLogicTree(logicTree);
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for really exposing to me the benefits of lists. Reduced my code by about 20 lines and I also implemented it in SolveLogicTree(). Great stuff!